# CSS properties not available

Tags: html, css, properties

I am using MS expression 4 for building this website and when I try to set some properties they are not available. The two I have come across so far are border-radius and background-size. I am sure I will come across more but I was wondering why that is and how I can get them so I can use them. the error says "the property is marked invalid because it is not covered by the current schema"

Thank you

Comment: It seems that MS expression 4 is little outdated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your project is setup to use a css version that doesn't support boder-radius and background-size. These are both css3 properties so I guess you are using css 2.x. If you want to use those properties, you have to use css 3.

Check this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bK_5GJz_bM) at 1:07 to see how you can change your setup.